# Is it possible to apply Google search by image to a specific set of images?

Tags: image-processing, search-engine, google-image-search

I would like to use google's 'search by image' feature to search a defined set of images (rather than the entire web) for matches. Has anyone done this previously or do they know if it is possible?

Comment: can you provide an example?

Comment: Well I've not got the collection of images yet because I wanted to make sure it was possible first.

But I am trying to find matches for photos that I have some geographic information about. So I would like to apply search by image to deference images within a set distance from a location.

Comment: 'georeferenced' -that should say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

If you enter the image url, the search will be performed directly, however afterwards you can just type in additional keywords, or for example a domain.

If you want to search in a set of images that typically cannot be found by google, then it will probably not be possible.